# FlipperKit 'facebook::flipper::SocketCertificateProvider' (aka 'int') is not a function or function pointer template named 'function' in namespace std

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Called object type 'facebook::flipper::SocketEventHandler' (aka 'int') is not a function or function pointer
/Users/apple/Desktop/vipul/app/onPurpose/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Flipper/FlipperTransportTypes.h:29:14 No template named 'function' in namespace 'std'

getting error for FlipperKit

When create a build getting error
how to resolve this error

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find temp fix with
adding

> #include  `<functional>` 
> to 
> ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperTransportTypes.h
>
> may be an flipper needs an upgrade

Edit: can confirm flipper repo has this patch facebook/flipper@b3dcdb8
If you want change in pod file so use

Answer (score 1):

- Modify FlipperTransportTypes.h and add bellow code to line 9

  ```
  #include <functional>
  ```

[image]

- If you still want to use flipper, then modify your Podfile & add this to your post_install.

  ```
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'Flipper'
        file_path = 
  'Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperTransportTypes.h'
        contents = File.read(file_path)
        unless contents.include?('#include <functional>')
          File.open(file_path, 'w') do |file|
            file.puts('#include <functional>')
            file.puts(contents)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
  ```